# MySQL order by using some attribute

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I got a table category as follow
category_id
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8

I ran `SELECT category_id from category order by category_id > 3 DESC, category_id;`

the result is
category_id
4
5
6
7
8
1
2
3
 can anyone explain
1) why this result?
2) what does "order by category_id > 3" ?
3) what does the second expression "category_id" do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current `ORDER BY` clause has two sorting levels:

```
ORDER BY
    category_id > 3 DESC,
    category_id;
```

The first level `category_id > 3` is a boolean expression, and will be 0 (false) or 1 (true).  But because you order this level descending, the true case will be first.  This means that all `category_id` values greater than 3 will appear before all `category_id` values less than 3.

Then, the second sort order is `category_id`.  This means that within each of the two above mentioned groups, the values will be ordered ascending by the `category_id`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But when I switch the order of the sql statement as "ORDER BY category_id, category_id > 3 DESC", I expect  4 5 6 7 8 1 2 3, but the result is 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8. Is my concept wrong?

Comment: @WorkingSlave No, your output is expected.  You are ordering by `category_id` first, and then second by the `category_id > 3` restriction.  But, each level in the first order is unique, so the second level effectively gets ignored.

Answer (score 1):

This is your `order by`:

```
order by category_id > 3 DESC, category_id
```

MySQL treats a boolean expression as an integer, in a context where this is necessary.  So `category_id > 3` is treated as an integer, with 1 for true and 0 for false.

So, this puts all the categories greater than 3 (true) first, because true > false (1 > 0).  Within each group, the categories are arranged by id.

Comment: if I apply the same logic with the sql condition swapped, "order by category_id, category_id > 3 DESC", it is expected to give 4 5 6 7 8 1 2 3, but it gives 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8. @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @WorkingSlave . . . No.  You would want `ASC` rather than `DESC`.